# How use symbolic names for coordinates and scaling?

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the correct syntax for accomplishing what I hope is clearly indicated in the following non-working TikZ code?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}    
\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}    
  \coordinate (basePt) at (4, 2);
  % HOW  accomplish this multiplication with hard-coded factors?
  \coordinate (newPt) at (0.65,0.65)*basePt; % or perhaps 0.65*basePt
  %  And how to do it if, instead, a "symbolic name", e.g., myscale, were used?
  %  and how define that symbolic name?
  % Missing here: how to define myscale to be, e.g., 0.65?
  \coordinate (newerPt) at myscale*basePt;
  \draw (0,0) -- (basePt) -- (newerPt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In other words, how does one do calculations with coordinates — both with specific numbers and then with symbolic names for such numbers — and then how does one define the value of such a symbolic name?

My purpose is to be able easily to modify just the value of a couple of named variables at the beginning of the `tikzpicture` code rather than having to change coordinate values throughout the code.

Comment: What is `(0.65,0.65)*basePt` supposed to represent? if you want to to proceed along a vector than using  `($(0,0)!0.5!(basePt)$)` will get you half way from the origin to`(basePt)`.  I think this needs the `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` library.

Comment: @PeterGrill: `(0.65,0.65)*basePt` is supposed to represent a new point each of whose coordinates is obtained by multiplying the corresponding coordinate of `basePt` by `0.65`. That's the first thing I'm trying to do, and you just told me how to do it. But how can I do the same thing and use a *symbolic* name for `0.65` (something one can do in every programming language I've ever used).

Answer (score 3):

The `calc` library lets you calculate coordinates, see section 13.5 *Coordinate calculations* in the manual. You can for example use `declare function` to define `myscale`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}    
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={myscale=0.65;}
  ]
  \coordinate (basePt) at (4, 2);

  \coordinate (newPt) at ($0.65*(basePt)$); % 

  \coordinate (newerPt) at ($myscale*(basePt)$);
  \draw (0,0) -- (basePt) node{a} -- (newerPt) node{b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this mean that the only way to define a *constant* such as `myScale` to be used in code is (i) as a `function` and (ii) as an option to `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @murray No and no. You could use `\tikzset{declare function={..}}` in the preamble, instead of in the `tikzpicture` option. But you don't have to use a function at all, you could do e.g. `\newcommand\somescale{0.65}`, and use `\somescale` in the coordinate calculation.

Comment: Using `\newcomand...` is just ordinary LaTeX. But is there some way in the TikZ language to declare a symbolic constant other than `declare function={..}`?

Comment: @murray In this context, the only other thing I can think of is `\pgfmathsetmacro` (and some other similar ones), but that's just another way of declaring a macro holding a number — with the addition that you can can do calculations in the definition.